# How to put timestamp in express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack, node-modules

I tried putting timestamp for all my requests.I used morgan for that and i include like below,

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // Enable logger (morgan)
    app.use(morgan('common'));
  }
```

This results in my console as,

```
::ssss:197.7.8.1 - - [Fri, 28 Apr 2017 00:28:29 GMT] "GET /assets/jqwidgets/styles/images/icon-right.png HTTP/1.1" 200 143
::ssss:197.7.8.1 - - [Fri, 28 Apr 2017 00:28:29 GMT] "GET /assets/jqwidgets/styles/images/icon-left.png HTTP/1.1" 200 139
::ssss:197.7.8.1- - [Fri, 28 Apr 2017 00:28:31 GMT] "GET /admin-get-users
```

From the above results I i am getting the timestamp as well as the internet address(::ssss:197.7.8.10which i dont want.Can anyone please suggest me help.I f any new module suggested is also a good solution for me.Thanks.

Comment: What do you want then ?

Comment: If only, if only there was [documentation for this](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for how to get the timestamp with Morgan, not expressjs. You should probably retag the question appropriately.

In any event, [morgan offers some predefined tokens](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#tokens) you use when constructing the object to set up the string it outputs. If you're *only* interested in the timestamp use `app.use(morgan(':date[format]'));` to construct the object where format is one of `clf` (prints like "27/Apr/2017:12:00:00 +0000", `iso` (prints like "2017-04-27T12:00:00.000Z"), or `web` (prints like "Thu, 27 Apr 2017 12:00:00 GMT"). Other tokens also exist like `:status` for the HTTP status code of the response or `:url` for the url of the request. if you find you're interested in logging those. After your comment it seems you are, so try `app.use(morgan(':date[clf] ":method :url"'));` or `app.use(morgan(':date[clf] ":url"'));`.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // Enable logger (morgan)
    app.use(morgan(':date[clf] ":method :url"')); // prints date in same format as original Q
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter,with this change I am getting Fri, 28 Apr 2017 04:15:10 GMT
only time stamp.I want timestamp with my request url.

Comment: I've updated the post to include the request url. If you don't want the "GET" or "POST" or whatever, just take out the `:method` from the string.

Comment: I solved it using  app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :response-time :date[clf]'));

Comment: Peter,can you tell how to include color also.

Comment: that part seems a little more difficult. Look at line 150 of the source file here: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js ... You'll need to use `compile` I think as well as the special format characters like `\x1b[]`. It might not be worth it seeing as there's no official API for it, honestly. If you find you *really* need to know how to do this, it probably needs another question so this one isn't "too broad".